# how to remove "(x)" from a string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm working on tennis database and I would like to remove "(x)" from scores.

For example : 
 `7-6(7) 6-2 --> 7-6 6-2`

I try :

```
gsub("(2)","",Tennis2017_table$score)
```

just to see if I could remove the "(2)" but it only removed all the "2"

```
gsub("\\(|\\)", "", Tennis2017_table$score)
```

but it only remove ()

I've searched similar problems and try to adapt the issue to mine but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsub("\\(.\\)","",Tennis2017_table$score)
```

if your 'x' is a number

- use `\\d` instead of `.`

If you have multiple numbers `(14)` use:

- use `\\d+` instead of `.`

---

additional info:

- learn as much about `regular expression` as possible.
- `(` and `)` have special meaning in regEx. That's why you need to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `gsub` uses a regular expression and both `(` and `)` are meta characters. You need to use the following regex : `\(x\)` where `x` is the character to remove. If you want to remove any integer, use `\\(\\d+\\)`. Cf. [R gsub documentation](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php)